# Нужно ли знать, почему заяц пишется через Я?

Tags: орфография

**Из форума:** "Еще со школы помню как сама задавала этот вопрос. Сейчас уже все ясно и понятно, а в детстве "заец" писала часто пока мама не объяснила, что надо всегда писать "заяц" и это надо запомнить". (Запятых нет).

"Каких только вариантов произношения слова "заяц" не услышишь. И "заЕц" и "заИц". Безграмотных людей сейчас много. Верное написание и произношение слова "заЯц" надо запомнить, так как оно является словарным". (Кажется, произношение и написание никак не различаются).

Действительно, заяц - словарное слово, но запись таких слов связана с их этимологией. **Может мы не правы, ограничивая детский интерес этой формулой - словарное слово.** Мне кажется, что многие наши наивные пользователи считают, что кто-то в орфографической комиссии предложил: "А давайте будем писать для разнообразия  "заяц", и все проголосовали. Или они ничего не считают?

**И кстати, почему там пишется Я?** Шанский говорит о корне "зай" и суффиксах  ęць > яц, как в слове "месяц". Но почему у нас так мало слов с  суффиксом ЯЦ, а вот суффикс ЯК применяется часто: белый - беляк, резать - резак, три - трояк, ветер - ветряк.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Интерес детей к этому вопросу иллюстрирует такая работа:
http://nsportal.ru/ap/library/drugoe/2012/10/19/issledovanie-slovarnogo-slova-zayats

Но даже после знакомства со словарными версиями этимологии неясности остаются. Гипотеза происхождения от глагола "заяти", который мог бы списать "я" на старинное ударение, производит двойственное впечатление: из того же "заяти" выводят глагол "занять", смысл которого с зайцем труднее связать (почти как "паять" с "паяц").
https://slovari.yandex.ru/~%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8/%d0%ad%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9%20%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8c/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c/

Если это слово устояло в длительной борьбе за единообразие правил словообразования, нельзя исключить, что дело в его корне, а не в предполагаемом суффиксе. Поэтому заслуживает внимания и такая гипотеза, основанная на древней форме слова zājemikis: "В современном русском слове ЗАЯЦ корнем является всё."
http://literra.listbb.ru/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=1367

Comment: Корень, скорее всего, "зай", а суффиксы могли быть разные, сравнить: зАек, зАек,  зАешки (болг.), старославянская запись заѩць,  в русском языке носовой ę перешел в я. Черных также сравнивает корни zai и  ghai (gait , goat - коза, тоже прыгучее животное.

Answer (score 1):

От глагола "заяти" — прыгать, скакать. Сейчас такого глагола в русском нет, поэтому и словарное.

> > Может мы не правы, ограничивая детский интерес этой формулой - словарное слово.

Детский интерес ограничить невозможно, если он есть. А если нет, ну что ж... Пусть человек просто грамотно пишет, не велика трудность запомнить этого самого "заЯца".

Comment: Тогда: лаять - лаяц, веять - веяц, где все эти слова? А месяц от месять? Одного "зайца", конечно, не трудно запомнить, но таких "зайцев" целый словарь, все в голове не помещаются. .Развивается интуитивная грамота, но на запятые, на различение произношения и письма интеллекта не хватает. Кроме того, обратите внимания, у людей и нет потребности в каких-то объяснениях, они даже, скорее всего, не знают об их существовании в принципе, они всё принимают на веру.

Comment: А интерес нужно развивать в школе, для чего они тогда туда ходят?  И есть прямая зависимость интерес -способность к творчеству - успешное развитие страны.

Comment: Вы начали про зайца, а именно про букву Я. А закончили чем? Почему "тогда: лаять - лаяц, веять - веяц"? Вот почему так должно быть, откуда это следует? Далее. Если школьник много читает (или хотя  бы средне), то грамотность у него будет нормальной, выше средней. А если стать на вашу позицию, то на другие предметы школьнику уже и времени не останется.

Comment: >> ***у людей и нет потребности в каких-то объяснениях, они даже, скорее всего, не знают об их существовании в принципе, они всё принимают на веру***. Вас интересует теория относительности? А квантовая механика? Причем не на пальцах, а прям с формулами, на уровне физфака? Интересует вас TCP-протокол? И так далее... Признайте же, что есть вещи поважнее, чем тонкости языка.

Comment: Дети в школе решают дифференциальные  уравнения, считают интегралы, это высокий уровень знаний, а пригодится он очень немногим. Грамотный русский язык нужен каждому, а у нас уровень 11-го класса мало чем отличается от уровня 5-го класса, мне кажется, школьников просто оберегают от нормального знания языка, боятся объяснять самые простые вещи. Но я даже не об этом.  На примере русского языка, как и других дисциплин, можно развивать мышление и творческие наклонности учащихся. Стремление думать, анализировать должно  поощряться, в отличие от желания все принимать на веру и учить наизусть.

Comment: Дифференциальные уравнения не решают, а интегралы берут ну самые простенькие. Это не такой высокий уровень, ничего особенного, уж поверьте. Да, напрямую не пригодится, но математика развивает мозги будь здоров. А какое отношение имеет "заяц" к грамотному русскому языку? Допустим, я не знаю происхождение (классе в пятом и правда не знал), но пишу ведь правильно? Далее. Ведь заяц не единственный, таких слов сотни тысяч. Да почти каждое. Что же, задаваться происхождением каждого слова? Вот ЭТО в жизни уж точно не пригодится.

Comment: Развитым на математике мозгам  (а на это уходит уйма времени) хорошо бы найти достойное практическое применение в других областях жизни, например изучить русскую  грамматику на более достойном уровне и применять свои знания в повседневной речи. Не обязательно знать подробности о каждом словарном слове, но человек должен понимать, что каждая буква там не случайна и при желании можно узнать, почему мы пишем Я, а не Е. А потом отвечать на форуме. Но люди даже не понимают ограниченность своих знаний:  как я уже говорила, для них произношение и написание - это одно и то же.

Comment: >> **для них произношение и написание - это одно и то же** Это уж вы слишком... МОлОкО никто не произносит, кроме вологжан.

Comment: Цитирую: "Каких только вариантов ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЯ слова "заяц" не услышишь. И "заЕц" и "заИц". Безграмотных людей сейчас много. Верное написание и произношение слова "заЯц" надо запомнить, так как оно является словарным". А вы какую гласную  произносите в слове "заяц"?

Comment: Ну и что? Не надо придираться. Такие всегда будут.

Comment: Таких большинство, а эти лучшие среди них.  У них хотя бы есть интерес к русскому языку, но при этом у них плохое образование.  И не только их стоит винить в этом.

Comment: Непонятно, что вы предлагаете. Увеличить число уроков русского языка втрое? И пройти в 11-м классе первый курс филфака? Или просто поощрять у детей интерес к языку? Если первое, то это абсолютно несбыточно; если второе -- вы ломитесь в открытую дверь.

Comment: Нужно повышать качество образования, а не количество часов. В школу должны прийти люди творческие, любящие свой предмет, открытые новым знаниям,  способные вести с учащимися диалог. А для этого учитель должен иметь  высокую зарплату, небольшую  загруженность и свободу от всяких бюрократических обязанностей. Тогда эта профессия будет престижной для молодежи. Но такой, возможно,  будет только школа будущего.

Comment: "Высокая зарплата и небольшая загруженность" -- я тоже такое хочу. ))) Нет, благих пожеланий у меня тоже мильён. Но я знаю учителя (правда, истории), которая любит свой предмет, открыта новым знаниям, и у которой БОЛЬШАЯ (даже очень) загруженность и именно потому высокая зарплата. А ваш учитель, наверно, живет на Утопии. )))

Comment: При большой загруженности трудно быть в курсе новых научных достижений, особенно в истории. И на индивидуальные занятия с  талантами и будущими светилами науки времени не останется.

Comment: Поймите вы, что школа не знакомит с "новыми научными достижениями". Никого и никогда. Это просто невозможно (школьники к этому не готовы), да и не нужно. Мало нам профанаций? Школа занимается гораздо более важным делом: она учит думать. (По крайней мере, должна этим заниматься). Если ученик научился думать, он сам познакомится с новыми научными, если будет интерес. И еще: столько светил науки обществу не нужно. Кто-то должен и у станка стоять.

Comment: Я про учителя говорю, это он должен быть в курсе достижений и не отставать от жизни. В противном случае он будет сейчас говорить то же, что говорил 20 лет назад, ДУМАТЬ так, как думали тогда, а мир меняется стремительно, иногда и через год жизнь уже совсем другая.